# Good practices in Angular Reactive Forms (property vs getter)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

Im trying to create a form to edit the items in my data base. I have seen different ways to handle the forms but i am not sure if one way is better or if or if it depends on the characteristics of the form.

This is the interface of the items in my database:

```
export interface Statistician {
    id:           string;
    name:         string;
    birthplace:    string;
    institution:  string;
    topics:       any;
    maininterest: string;
}
```

The form:

```
  public editForm = this.formBuilder.group({

    id:          [""],
    name:         [""],
    birthplace:    [""],
    institution:  [""],
    topics:       [],
    maininterest: [""],
  })
```

**First option:**

Get the item information and reset the form with it, then create a getter to handle this information.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ActivatedRoute.params
    .pipe(
      switchMap(({id}) => this.StatisciansService.getStatbyId(id))
    )
    .subscribe(resp => this.editForm.reset(resp))
  }
```

```
  get currentStat():Statistician{
    const stat = this.editForm.value as Statistician
    return stat
  }
```

```
      onSubmit(){
    if (this.editForm.invalid) return


      this.StatisciansService.onEdit(this.currentStat)
      .subscribe()
  }
```

**Second option:**

Get the item information, then create a property to handle this information.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ActivatedRoute.params
    .pipe(
      switchMap(({id}) => this.StatisciansService.getStatbyId(id))
    )
    .subscribe(resp => this.DataForm = resp)
  }
```

```
  public formData = {
    id:          "",
    name:         "",
    bithplace:    "",
    institution:  "",
    topics:       [],
    maininterest: "",
  }
```

Finally, insert the data changed in the form:

```
  onSubmit(){

    
    if (this.editForm.invalid) return
    this.formData.name = this.editForm.value['name']!
    this.formData.maininterest = this.editForm.value['maininterest']!
    this.formData.topics = this.editForm.value['topics']!
    

      this.StatisciansService.onEdit(this.formData)
      .subscribe()

  }
```

In the first option, the data is changed in the getter while the user use the form. In my case i have an img in the template with the src associated with the name in the getter. When i change the name, the image dissapear.
I know that it can be solved by associating the src with data that is not in the form, such as an id, but I wonder if there is a similar situation where I don't want the data from the form to be passed to the component automatically.

In the second option i wait to the onSubmit method to change the data in the property.

In summary, what option do you recommend to handle the data of a reactive form? I'm doing something wrong, is there a better option?

Thank you!